# SSD with bad sectors, how do I mark them as bad? A lot of drive utilities wont work because Windows won't assign it a drive letter

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

So, I have an SSD with some bad blocks, 86 according to crystalDiskInfo. It has shown some signs of life and it would be really nice to have as a games drive. The SSD is a PALIT PH120.

**TL;DR**: I want to mark some blocks as bad on a drive that windows isn't assigning a drive letter.

Here are all the troubleshooting steps I have taken from start to finish:

The SSD came out of an old mini-PC originally used in a photo booth. It had inconsistent behaviour in that mini-PC, usually the BIOS will throw a "failed to read disk" error and shows up correctly in the BIOS but occasionally it says it cannot find a disk at all and it will not show up in the BIOS config.

When in a working PC it was detected and showed up in partition manager as having 2 blocks, one was 500MB and was the windows recovery partition, this was not corrupted at all and I was able to read the files in it like normal. The other was marked as "RAW" file system in disk management and could not be read by file explorer (it showed up but did not report a size and would prompt me to format the drive). The drive originally had windows 8 on it.

I assumed the old windows install was just corrupted so I put it back in the mini-PC and attempted to install windows 10 clean, when it asked me to select the drive it showed up as unallocated so I selected "new" to create a new partition. This just threw an error message. I tried allocating 1GB less then the default but same issue.

I then put the drive back in my working PC to format it there and when I opened disk management it showed a dialog box saying it needs to initialise it and asks me if I want to use GPT or MBR partition styles, selecting either option just throws a `Data error (cyclic redundancy check).` The drive shows as "not initialised" and shows the correct amount of space as unallocated. The options to format it are greyed out. It does not appear in file explorer at all. Going to properties just says "This device is working properly." and reports all info about the drive correctly.

In event viewer there are loads of errors from `disk` saying `The device, \Device\Harddisk0\DR0, has a bad block.` and an error from `Virtual Disk Service` saying `VDS fails to write boot code on a disk during clean operation. Error code: 80070017@02070008`, these errors will appear after running disk management.

There is also this in event viewer under the drives events:

```
Device SCSI\Disk&Ven_PALIT&Prod_PH120_SSD\5&6b81732&0&000000 was configured.
Driver Name: disk.inf
Class Guid: {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Driver Date: 06/21/2006
Driver Version: 10.0.22000.832
Driver Provider: Microsoft
Driver Section: disk_install.NT
Driver Rank: 0xFF0005
Matching Device Id: GenDisk
Outranked Drivers: 
Device Updated: false
Parent Device: PCI\VEN_1022&DEV_7901&SUBSYS_08D71028&REV_61\4&1c1a44e&0&0042
```

I then opened up crystalDiskInfo and it reports no drive letter (windows did not assign it a drive letter), 99% health and 86 bad blocks.

From what I can tell the rest of the drive is fine, the fact I was able to read the data in the recovery partition (before the windows 10 installer deleted it to make a new volume) shows that the rest of the drive is working. How can I create a partition that excludes the bad blocks?

It does also seem to consistently give the "failed to read disk" error and will consistently show up in the BIOS of the mini-PC. No more failing to see the drive (probably needed to be reseated as it had been sitting around for a few years)

Comment: “It showed a dialog box saying it needs to initialize it and asks me if I want to use GPT or MBR partition styles” - This is a strong indication the drive has failed. It means the partition table is lost. On a SSD the firmware of the drive has total control over which cells can or cannot be used. Windows 8.1 suggests a drive that is more than a decade old, which matches, what the lifecycle of a drive like that is expected to have. I am not aware of any way to mark a sector of the drive bad on any SSD since that sector of the file system could be instantly be moved by the firmware.

Comment: I am not even sure I would say that an SSD even has sectors, since file fragmentation, doesn’t exist on that type of media (or if it does it’s not a performance issue and traditionally nothing can be done about it)

Comment: I did use the wrong terminology there, I should have said "blocks" not "sectors"

Comment: With modern disks, generally which sectors are bad is hidden from the end user. Especially on SSDs - where you have scrambling or encryption as part of the wear levelling process, 'old school' bad block checking is meaningless. In theory formatting the drive (or in the case of SSDs, possibly running trim) *should* deal with bad blocks but you do need to get an initial format on the drive.

Comment: I'd like to know why my (old) answer has been deleted?? I can accept downvotes if people disagree, I can edit the answer if needed, but I don't get a straight delete, as the answer was not breaking any rule on SU.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest replacing the drive right away.

To the extent that it is running (that is, your computer is running), back it up right now using a USB drive.

You may not get everything (given the errors), but the sooner you back up, the more you will recover.

Comment: If you read the question you will see that the drive is unreadable (not formatted), I am asking how to allocate the sectors as bad. I will of course not be using it to store anything important as it is failing.

Comment: SSD's do not have physical sectors. Good SSD's have extra cells that they use to take the place of older (non working) cells, but I still think you should be replacing this drive.

Comment: Are there any tools that can allocate partitions around faulty sectors?

Comment: No.  not on an SSD drive.

Comment: Ok, good to know.

Comment: Anything that can do a read write scan or zero fill should trigger 'bad sector' replacements but this does not mean a drive is now reliable. Whether Windows assigns a drive letter or not is irrelevant. 'Health' as determined in many SMART tools is a too simplistic approach and should not relied on.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen what would be a good tool to do this?

Comment: Anything that writes zeros from first LBA to the last. In Linux for example dd. I think DBAN is self booting, just settle for one pass with zeros. Most drive manufacturers provide some tool that can do it too.

Comment: People are again running around downvoting old question. Would the downvoter please POST a REASON... Thank you